# asmack Not sharing big file in android

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am implementing XMPP Client app in android for file sharing using:

1. asmack-android-19-0.8.10.jar
2. FileTransferNegotiator.IBB_ONLY = true; for sending and receiving.

My code is send/receive images and small audio/video(under 1mb) properly,
but for big image is processing and at the last showing below error and all file is not receiving.

Please someone can help ?

```
06-06 13:32:09.370: D/SMACK(19331): 01:32:09 PM SENT (1096333592): 
<iq id="n1K2O-178" to="newchat@appazineapp.com/Smack" type="set">
    <data
        xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb" seq="165" sid="jsi_6939764179431327669">Tt5G7Pgf2PvVYHEMtzgHaIDP1VeE7.........
06-06 13:32:10.480: D/SMACK(19331): 01:32:10 PM RCV  (1096333592): 
        <iq id="n1K2O-177" to="admin@appazineapp.com/Smack" from="newchat@appazineapp.com/Smack" type="result"/>
06-06 13:32:11.300: D/SMACK(19331): 01:32:11 PM RCV  (1096333592): 
        <iq id="n1K2O-178" to="admin@appazineapp.com/Smack" from="newchat@appazineapp.com/Smack" type="error">
            <data
                xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb" seq="165" sid="jsi_6939764179431327669">Tt5G7Pgf2PvVYHEMtzgHaIDP1VeE7jNNvnhIKVu/o6JXl8dpM9GHHEy+UBs8lk0QLTrxmZAoPW7eoEd........
            </data>
            <error code="400" type="WAIT">
                <unexpected-request
                    xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
                </error>
            </iq>

    05-28 20:38:58.011: W/System.err(4044): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: IQ must be of type 'set' or 'get'. Original IQ: 
<iq id="4flBi-289" to="newchat@appazineapp.com/Smack" from="admin@appazineapp.com/Smack" type="error">
    <data
        xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb" seq="275" sid="jsi_6594777956963977527">Y0oP6SaIJPaqRXq1X3Ck8nvfF8LiaNno.......
    05-28 20:38:58.021: W/System.err(4044):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.IQ.createResultIQ(IQ.java:137)
    05-28 20:38:58.021: W/System.err(4044):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.ibb.InBandBytestreamSession$IQIBBInputStream$1.processPacket(InBandBytestreamSession.java:473)
    05-28 20:38:58.031: W/System.err(4044):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection$ListenerWrapper.notifyListener(Connection.java:867)
    05-28 20:38:58.031: W/System.err(4044):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$ListenerNotification.run(PacketReader.java:455)
    05-28 20:38:58.031: W/System.err(4044):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
    05-28 20:38:58.031: W/System.err(4044):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    05-28 20:38:58.031: W/System.err(4044):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    05-28 20:38:58.041: W/System.err(4044):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    05-28 20:38:58.041: W/System.err(4044):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    05-28 20:38:58.041: W/System.err(4044):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Could you get the entire error stanza somehow?  It starts with `type=error`, so it's supposed to contain a specific error element, but presumably that's after the data element, and thus truncated in the stack trace above.

Comment: That error IQ is strange. I'm not even sure if IBB error IQs are supposed to contain a `data` element. It would definitely help if you would show us the complete stanza.

Comment: Thanks legoscia/Flow,  type=error is showing at last I have edited the response, please check again stanza before type=error, if you have any probability to solve it please let me know.

Comment: [XEP-0047](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0047.html) says that `unexpected-request` is returned if the sequence number has already been used.  Is it possible that the sequence number is not being incremented correctly?

Comment: These IQ stanzas are create, send or receive by asmack jar, how we can know its incremented correctly or not ?

Comment: @legoscia, can we create and send custom IQ Stanzas for send file using IBB http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0047.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of uploading images using openfire you can also create a java plugin which can upload your files on the server and then you can send your friend the absolute path just like whatsapp uses.

I will sooner post the overall code also.
Hope this works !